# How to convert st_mtime (which get from stat function) to string or char

Tags: c, datetime, android-ndk, string-conversion

I need to convert st_mtime to string format for passing it to java layer, i try to use this example http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/10342/ but compiler produce errors

> invalid conversion from 'long unsigned int*' to 'const time_t* {aka
>   long int const*}'
>
> initializing argument 1 of 'tm* localtime(const time_t*)'
>   [-fpermissive]

What i doing wrong, how to get time creation of file using stat function in string presentation.

Help please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [stat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) man page, the `st_mtime` field is a `time_t` (i.e. after reading the [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man page, a number of seconds since the [unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

You need [localtime(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/localtime.3.html) to convert that `time_t` to a `struct tm` in local time, then, [strftime(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strftime.3.html) to convert it to a `char*` string.

So you could code something like:

```
time_t t = mystat.st_mtime;
struct tm lt;
localtime_r(&t, &lt);
char timbuf[80];
strftime(timbuf, sizeof(timbuf), "%c", &lt);
```

then use `timbuf` perhaps by `strdup`-ing it.

NB. I am using `localtime_r` because it is more thread friendly.

Comment: If you're not fussy about the format, you can also just pass the time_t into "ctime" to get a string.  (Note ctime isn't thread-safe.)

Comment: But the OP needs a thread-safe solution, because it is inside a JVM.

Answer (score 10):

use `strftime()` there's an example in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) something like:

```
struct tm *tm;
char buf[200];
/* convert time_t to broken-down time representation */
tm = localtime(&t);
/* format time days.month.year hour:minute:seconds */
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tm);
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Would print the output:

```
"24.11.2012 17:04:33"
```

Comment: Where did you get `t`?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in an alternative way:

1. Declare a pointer to a `tm` structure:

   ```
   struct tm *tm;
   ```
2. Declare a character array of proper size, which can contain the time string you want:

   ```
   char file_modified_time[100];
   ```
3. Break the `st.st_mtime` (where `st` is a `struct` of type `stat`, i.e. `struct stat st`) into a local time using the function `localtime()`:

   ```
   tm = localtime(&st.st_mtim);
   ```

   Note: `st_mtime` is a macro (`#define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec`) in the man page of [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).
4. Use `sprintf()` to get the desired time in string format or whatever the format you'd like:

   ```
   sprintf(file_modified_time, "%d_%d.%d.%d_%d:%d:%d", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
   ```

NB: You should use

```
memset(file_modified_time, '\0', strlen(file_modified_time));
```

before `sprintf()` to avoid the risk of any garbage which arises in multi-threading.