# stack smashing detected by valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, program-entry-point, stack-dump

a stack smashing is detected in my main function in a c++ code... 
here is the body of main:

```
int main()
{
    long int acn;
    char dot[15];
    float open_balance=1;
    char k;
    int total_account=0;
    int c;
    static int ac=10000;
    TRANSACTION trn;
    support sprt;
    do{

        cout<<"\n1.New account\n2. Transaction\n3. Exit\n\nEnter choice:"; 
        cin>>k;
        switch(k) { 
            case '1':

                ac+=1;
                time_t rawtime;
                time(&rawtime);
                strcpy(dot,ctime(&rawtime));
                do{
                    if(open_balance<=0)
                        cout<<"Opening BALANCE can not be less than zero";
                    cout<<"\nEnter the opening balance :";
                    cin>>open_balance;
                }while(open_balance<=0);
                bln[total_account].get_data(ac,open_balance,dot);
                ++total_account;
                break;
            case '2':
                trn.trans(total_account);
                break;
            case '3': break;
            default :
                      cout<<"\nWrong choice!!";
        }
    }while(k!='3');
    cout<<"Thank you";
    return(0);
}
```

When i run the code through valgrind it also finds the stack smashing but can't find any memory leak.
valgrind report:

> 1.New account
>   2. Transaction
>   3. Exit
>
> Enter choice:3
>   *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated Thank you==9813==
>
> ==9813== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==9813==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==9813==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 954 bytes allocated
>
> ==9813==
>
> ==9813== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>
> ==9813==
>
> ==9813== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==9813== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0) Aborted (core dumped)

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Here the explanation for "stack smashing" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected

Comment: Something tells me 15 `char`s isn't enough to store the result of `time`.

Comment: Agree with @user657267 "Fri Oct 24 10:42:10 2014" definitely greater then destination buffer char dot[15];

Comment: You should use [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13542418/841108). You should compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 2):

it's the line `strcpy(dot,ctime(&rawtime));` which causes the stack smeshing.
function `ctime` returns a string alike `"Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"`, its length is more than 15 bytes, and you need more bytes to store the result of `ctime`.
`strcpy` does not check the margin of target memory, so it is considered dangerous, alternative `strncpy` is suggested instead. And, if your program runs more than one thread, `ctime_r` is preferred.